# Rewrite locale urls on nginx, but not for registration links

Tags: localization, registration, nginx, frontend-form

I'm using [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/williamgomes/5749c8f54936823af15c9f1a45713861) to rewrite the urls on a localized website running on nginx. It's working fine, except for the account activation links. They are localized as well, but they shouldn't. I'm sure there can be made an exception in the rewrite rule for all urls starting with /actions. But I don't know how. Can anybody help?